# Display soft-deleted records in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a rookie in Ruby on Rails, at the moment, I am developing a Rails application comes with soft delete feature. As you can see in the controller, in the index action, as an admin I will display records that are not included soft-deleted records as default.

But I want to make a checkbox or button on the page to include the soft-deleted records when I checked or click them. And I'm quite stuck right here, if anyone have a solution it would be great. Btw, don't hesitate to suggest a better approach for this situation. Any helps would be appreciated, I attach the controller and model below.

**Controller**

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :admin_user, only: %i(edit update)
  before_action :load_tour_detail, only: %i(create reduce_quantity cal_revenue)
  before_action :load_booking, except: %i(index new create index_with_deleted)
  after_action :reduce_quantity, :cal_revenue, only: :create
  after_action :increse_quantity, only: :destroy
  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
    @bookings = if current_user.admin?
                  Booking.includes(:tour_detail).not_deleted
                         .paginate(page: params[:page])
                else
                  Booking.includes(:tour_detail).where(user_id: current_user.id)
                         .paginate(page: params[:page])
                end
  end
```

**Model**

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tour_detail
  belongs_to :user
  validates :people_number, presence: true
  before_save :cal_price
  enum status: {pending: 1, confirmed: 2, cancelled: 3}
  scope :not_deleted, -> {where("deleted_at IS NULL")}
  scope :deleted, -> {where("deleted_at IS NOT NULL")}

  def soft_delete
    update deleted_at: Time.now
  end

  def recover
    update deleted_at: nil
  end
end
```

**UPDATE:**
I found a solution for this, I made a button on index page which pass a param to controller. Then on the controller I check the praram is it valid? And redirect my app to the right action that includes soft_deleted records or not. I will post the solution below just in case my explanation in English is too bad.
If someone has any better solution for this, please just suggest, it would be useful for me. Thank you guys!

**Controller**

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :admin_user, only: %i(edit update)
  before_action :load_tour_detail, only: %i(create reduce_quantity cal_revenue)
  before_action :load_booking, except: %i(index new create index_with_deleted)
  after_action :reduce_quantity, :cal_revenue, only: :create
  after_action :increse_quantity, only: :destroy
  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
    @bookings = if current_user.admin?
                  if params.has_key?(:soft_deleted)
                    Booking.includes(:tour_detail).all
                           .paginate(page: params[:page])
                  else
                    Booking.includes(:tour_detail).not_1deleted
                           .paginate(page: params[:page])
                  end
                else
                  Booking.includes(:tour_detail).where(user_id: current_user.id)
                         .paginate(page: params[:page])
                end
  end
```

**View**

```
<% if params.has_key?(:soft_deleted) %>
   <%= link_to bookings_path, class: "btn btn-sm btn-primary" do %>
     Only existed bookings
   <% end %>
<% else %>
   <%= link_to bookings_path(soft_deleted: true), class: "btn btn-sm btn-warning" do %>
     Included deleted bookings
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: `scope :not_deleted, -> { where(deleted_at: nil) }`. `scope :deleted, -> { where.not(deleted_at: nil)) }`.

Comment: @max Actually, my model scope is works when I test it in rails console, and this not what I meant. I meant to implement a checkbox in admin page when I checked it it will re-render the records which contains the soft-deleted records instead of only not_deleted records

Comment: The point was just that you can write it without using a SQL string.

Comment: @max Oh sorry man, thanks for your suggestion, appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below:

```
def index
    @bookings = if current_user.admin?
                  Booking.includes(:tour_detail)
                         .deleted(params[:checkbox_input_name]   # ----------> This line here
                         .paginate(page: params[:page])
                else
                  Booking.includes(:tour_detail)
                         .where(user_id: current_user.id)
                         .deleted(params[:checkbox_input_name]   # ----------> This line here

                         .paginate(page: params[:page])
                end
  end
```

And then in your `model`, add a scope like below:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  #   -----------------
  scope :deleted, -> lambda { |deleted_at| where("deleted_at IS NULL") if deleted_at.present? }

 # The above scope will return all objects if deleted_at param is not present. 
  private

  def soft_delete
    update deleted_at: Time.now
  end

  def recover
    update deleted_at: nil
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not what I meant in the question. I meant when you get the booking records with Admin which is not included soft_deleted records, I have an option to get soft_deleted records + not_deleted records when I check the checkbox.